# Scribus: InDesign like book object

Tags: scribus, publishing

I have been using Adobe InDesign to create books. I am considering shifting to Scribus. I usually make each chapter in my book into a separate document and then add all the documents to a InDesign book.

Is this possible in Scribus? What is the Scribus' method of book creation?

Comment: Looks like it's an external thing: https://github.com/JLuc/scribus-project-manager

Answer (score 0):

Scribus does not have the concept of "book" (yet).

There are two things you can do, if you (correctly) prefer to create the book in separate documents:

- At the end of the job, import all the documents in a main book document (but you might need lot of RAM)
- Create multiple PDFs and join those pdf with a pdf manipulation tool.

I can only hope that Scribus will have a good way to manage books in the future, but the developers might need help to get there.

Comment: I would suggest to go down the pdf merging path. Unless you need to make some edits while editing the book as a whole.